# How do i calculate and view total work_time for specific id in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have two tables employes and attendances . What I want is to sum work_time for each employe id and show in my view.

employes Table
id
attendances Table
id
employe_id
work_time

I want to sum work_time column for specific employe id. I am new to laravel so how do I do that with laravel eloquent.

```
Employe.php
```

```
class Employe extends Model{
use HasFactory;
protected $fillable=['id','employe_code','employe_name','workplace'];
public function employee(){return $this->hasMany(Attendance::class);}}
```

```
Attendance.php
```

```
class Attendance extends Model{use HasFactory;
protected$fillable['id','employe_id','attendence_date','clock_in','clock_out','work_time','attendence_status'];
public function employe()
{return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\employe', 'employe_id');}}
```

```
AttendanceController
```

```
public function attendance(){
    $attendances = Employe::all();
    $hour = Attendance::where('employe_id',1)->sum('work_time');
    return view('pages.Attendance.hour', compact('attendances','hour'));    }
```

````
hour.blade.php
```

                        <table id="datatable" class="table  table-hover table-sm table-bordered p-0" data-page-length="50"
                           style="text-align: center">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="alert-success">#</th>
                            <th class="alert-success">employe_code</th>
                            <th class="alert-success">employe_name</th>
                            <th class="alert-success">work_time</th>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        @foreach($attendances as $attendances)
                            <tr>
                                <td></td>
                                <td>{{ $attendances->employe_code }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $attendances->employe_name }}</td>
                                <td>Hour  {{ $hour }} </td>
                            </tr>
                            @endforeach
                    </table>
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only for Laravel 8.12 and above, you can use `withSum()`

First of all, correct the relation name in `Employe.php`

```
class Employe extends Model{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable=['id','employe_code','employe_name','workplace'];
    public function attendances(){ //<---- here
        return $this->hasMany(Attendance::class);
    }
}
```

Here is the controller

```
public function attendance(){
    $attendances = Employe::query()->withSum('attendances', 'work_time')->get();
    return view('pages.Attendance.hour', compact('attendances'));    
}
```

And the blade (kept the variable name `$attendances` but you should change it to employees)

```html
<table id="datatable" class="table  table-hover table-sm table-bordered p-0" data-page-length="50" style="text-align: center">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="alert-success">#</th>
        <th class="alert-success">employe_code</th>
        <th class="alert-success">employe_name</th>
        <th class="alert-success">work_time</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach($attendances as $employe)
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>{{ $employe->employe_code }}</td>
            <td>{{ $employe->employe_name }}</td>
            <td>Hour  {{ $employe->attendances_sum_work_time }} </td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
</table>
```